# Exception - Oracle to Db2

Tags: oracle, plsql, db2

Good afternoon

Oracle for DB2 procedures and I can't run on Exception:

```
Create or replace PROCEDURE SP_NOST
    BEGIN
        UPDATE DMTLDBR.TB_FATO_VALOR_NOST
           SET REG_VALREAL_CLTE = 'Other Customers'
         WHERE REG_VALREAL_CLTE = '-1';

        COMMIT ;  

    EXCEPTION 

        WHEN OTHERS THEN
             RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Erro : SP_NOST - UPDATE -1 : '|| SQLERRM );
    END ;
END
```

The error that appears is;

```
[Code: -104, SQL State: 42601]  An unexpected token "EXCEPTION" was found following "COMMIT ".  Expected tokens may include:  "  

".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.25.1301
```

Can anyone help me ???

Answer (score 0):

If your Db2 database is not enabled for Oracle compatibility, try something like this:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
create or replace PROCEDURE SP_NOST()
BEGIN
    declare exit handler for sqlexception
    begin
        declare v_message varchar(1024);
        get diagnostics exception 1 v_message = message_text;
        rollback work;
        set v_message = ' UPDATE -1 : '||coalesce(v_message,'-');
        signal sqlstate 'SP_NOST' set message_text = v_message;
        return 8;
    end;

        UPDATE DMTLDBR.TB_FATO_VALOR_NOST
           SET REG_VALREAL_CLTE = 'Other Customers'
         WHERE REG_VALREAL_CLTE = '-1';

        COMMIT ;  

END
@
```